Request sent to Azure ML Service for operation 'submitMLPipelineRun' failed with http status code 'Forbidden'
trigger a pipeline in Data Factory to trigger the pipeline in Azure Machine Learning but failed and receive this error:
Request sent to Azure ML Service for operation 'submitMLPipelineRun' failed with http status code 'Forbidden'.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Explain situation: I construct a pipeline upload a file.csv from my local machine to blob storage using Data Factory. When the data is uploaded, I want to trigger a pipeline (MLOPSTEST ...) in Azure Machine Learning but it fails. Things I have done to setup the pipeline.
I have tested the pipeline and it worked
enter image description here
I have setup Linked service in Data factory in order to setup the connection between Data Factory and Machine Learning. Also I add role "Contributor" for Data Factory to trigger the AML (Azure Machine Learning) pipeline.
I have looked up on Youtube as well as other sources but I can't find the solution. So I may ask for help from the community and I thank you anyone who spend time to figure out for me.
I want to the Azure machine learning pipeline to be triggered after data factory uploaded the data file.csv into blob storage.

Even though you have assigned the contributor role to the managed identity, you are still getting a forbidden error because your network has been restricted. This is due to the Machine Learning workspace having the Enabled from selected IP addresses option checked, as shown below:

To resolve this issue, either check the Enabled from all networks option and rerun the pipeline, or create a new private endpoint and access it.
Follow the solution from the UPDATE section to create a new private endpoint.
This example is for a storage account but also works for a Machine Learning workspace.
